# When does a comma follow an exclamatory 'oh' or 'ah'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, punctuation

When does a comma follow an exclamatory 'oh' or 'ah'?

#### Example 1 (no comma after *oh*)

> “Everybody can't come here, you know, how ridiculous can you get? There's just barely enough room on this planter box for you and me, and not much else! Oh you're crazy all right, Marshall, no doubt about it!” “Probably. You know though, we […].”
>   (The Cosmic Lady Was Right: An American Journey by Marshall Motz)

#### Example 2 (comma placed after *oh*)

> “Oh, my gosh,” Ronald cried out. “You destroyed my ship, what are you doing?”
>   (Monster Closet by G. L. Robins)

Is this only a matter of style, or are the uses of 'Oh' in the examples above somewhat different?

Comment: Style and misstyle, I'd say.  I see the comma after *Oh* as necessary.

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule, I'd say commas are used in place of exclamation marks - i.e. when the "Oh" or "Ah" are being used as exclamations:

> Oh! I forgot my keys!
>
> Ah! Now I understand!

> Oh, I forgot my keys!
>
> Ah, now I understand!

In contrast, commas look very out of place where the "Oh" or "Ah" is part of a flat idiom:

> Oh my gosh!
>
> Oh my God!

> ?Oh, my gosh!
>
> ?Oh, my God!

---

? marks questionable usage.

Comment: +1, I agree completely. I would add that I think the reason behind this is that the comma is in place when there would be a natural pause when speaking. You pause after the "oh" when you say *Oh, I forgot my keys!* but there is no pause in *Oh my god*. :)

Comment: However, there is a difference in the spoken stresses between "Oh!  I forgot my keys!" and "Oh, I forgot me keys!"

Answer (score 1):

It is not a matter of “style” but of convention.

Four hundred years ago introductory particles like *Oh*, *tut*, *ay* were **never** followed by commas. (Neither were nouns of address.)

> *Cos:* By Ladie ſir tis thirtie yeares at least. —*Romeo and Juliet*, Q1, 1597

A hundred years later they were **always** followed by commas, and that’s been the rule ever since.

Now many writers are abandoning the use. For the present, it carries an implication of hipness and colloquiality, but that's only because it contrasts with the prevailing rule: it’s “eye dialect”, exactly like spelling *have to* as “hafta”.

It may catch on, it may not. But it doesn’t mean anything linguistic.